# help in android Edit Text

Tags: android, android-edittext

hi all i have a lil problem in android edit text
actually i made an app in which i m using two text fields for user name and password and set EditText size manually like in 200dip format. now when there is no text in the Edit Text it is in perfect size like in the image below but when we start typing text and the text exceeds the size of editText Field then it Expand downwards like in second image below.
[image: EditText Before]
[image: EditText After in Expanded shape]

What I want is that when text exceeds the size of EditText, it should not Change its size. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:singleLine="true"` should work.

Answer (score 2):

add this property for EditText and check...

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do your ExitText to be single line. You can use [android:singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine) but it is deprecated and it's replaced by [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType). Use [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)=text for single line and [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)=textMultiline for multiline

Answer (score 0):

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Another property...